# Django ask for fill a form not required

Tags: html, django, django-views

I've a strange bug with my forms.
In a page I must hande 2 separate forms,
the 1st one have no problem at all and I can add the record in DB ,
the 2nd one raise me an error asking to fill a required data of 1st form.
The POST dictionary looks ok

Here the log:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['lvt5Ph2SA1xxFK4LMotdHOWk2JuZzYDo0OKWc77rKICYKYmemy3gl0dBphnRNcFb'], 'pk_atto': ['1.1'], 'pk_persona': ['1'], 'capacita': ['11'], 'Aggiungi_persona': ['persona'], 'tipo': ['fondo']}>
<ul class="errorlist"><li>pk_particella<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

the views:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if("Aggiungi_particella" in request.POST):
        save_atto = AttiPartenzeParticelleForm(request.POST)
    else:
        save_atto = AttiPartenzePersoneForm(request.POST)
        print(request.POST)
        print(save_atto.errors)
    if save_atto.is_valid():
        save_atto.save()
        return redirect('/aggiungi_atto_partenza' + '/' + str(save_atto['pk_atto'].value()))
```

the forms:

```
class AttiPartenzeParticelleForm(ModelForm):
    pk_atto = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Atti.objects.all(),
                                          widget=forms.Select
                                          (attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    pk_particella = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Particelle.objects.all(),
                                          widget=forms.Select
                                          (attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    capacita = forms.CharField(max_length=30,
                                    widget=forms.NumberInput
                                    (attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    tipo = forms.CharField(max_length=30, initial="fondo", widget=forms.TextInput (attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Acquisizioni_Cessioni_particella
        fields = '__all__'

class AttiPartenzePersoneForm(ModelForm):
    pk_atto = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Atti.objects.all(),
                                          widget=forms.Select
                                          (attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    pk_persona = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Persone.objects.all(),
                                          widget=forms.Select
                                          (attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    capacita = forms.CharField(max_length=30,
                                    widget=forms.NumberInput
                                    (attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    tipo = forms.CharField(max_length=30, initial="fondo", widget=forms.TextInput (attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Acquisizioni_Cessioni_particella
        fields = '__all__'
```

and the HTML

```
<div id="particella" class="content-section d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
    <form action="" method="POST" id="particella_f">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div style="visibility:hidden">
                {{ form.pk_atto|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-8">
                    {{ form.pk_particella|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    {{ form.capacita|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>

                <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <button form="particella_f" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg mt-5" type="submit" name="Aggiungi_particella" value="particella">
                            AGGIUNGI PARTICELLA
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div style="visibility:hidden">
                    {{ form.tipo|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>


<div id="persona" class="content-section d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
    <form action="" method="POST" id="persona_f">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div style="visibility:hidden">
                {{ persona.pk_atto|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-8">
                    {{ persona.pk_persona|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    {{ persona.capacita|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center">

                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg mt-5" form="persona_f" type="submit" name="Aggiungi_persona" value="persona">
                            AGGIUNGI PERSONA
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div style="visibility:hidden">
                    {{ form.tipo|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

soneone have any idea?
thx

Comment: Both forms are pointing to Acquisizioni_Cessioni_particella model. Is pk_particella a required field in the model, its not in the second form?

Comment: pk_particella is present only in the Acquisizioni_Cessioni_particella model

Comment: And both forms are referencing that model. So the issue is that the second form needs that field.